# how to set color in ruby pdf-writer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pdf-generation, pdf-writer

I'm using pdf-writer gem in ruby.

While drawing a table, i need to set the shade_color and shade_color2 of table so that the rows get the alternate shade and shade2 colors.

Can anyone tell me how to set them?

Like table.shade2 = Color::RGB::Magenta

But i have a hexa vaue like 989898. Now, how to use this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cool,

I found it by myself:

table.shade2 = Color::RGB.new(227,241,254)

The same can be used elsewhere:

table.line_color = Color::RGB.new(227,241,254)

Answer (score 1):

Just as a sidenote: PDF::Writer has been more or less abandoned and been replaced by [Prawn](http://Prawn.MajesticSeaCreature.Com/).

Comment: agree! The project was in maintenance mode and I didn't want to disturb any of the existing gem/plugin usage.